# How to write a blank line to a text file?

Tags: c, file-io, newline

I'm writing a program to keep an inventory of books, it reads a list of books from a text file and also writes additional books into the file. I got it to add new books to the file, but I would like to have a blank line between each book entry. How can I do that?
Some other info that might be useful or needed: I'm using a structure to hold the title, author, and ISBN all in character strings.

Here's the part that collects the new data:
It's put into a linked list.

```
puts("Enter first book title.");
while(fgets(input, 80, stdin) != NULL && input[0] != '\n')
{
current = (struct book *)malloc(sizeof(struct book));
if(head == NULL)
   head = current;
else
   prev->next = current;
current->next = NULL;

strcpy(current->title, input);
puts("Enter the author.");
fgets(current->author, 80, stdin);
puts("Enter the ISBN.");
fgets(current->ISBN, 80, stdin);

puts("Enter next book title (empty line to quit)");
prev = current;
}
```

Here's the part that writes to the file:

```
input_file = fopen("library.txt", "w"); 
printf("Printing list to file...\n");
while(current != NULL)
{
  fprintf(input_file,"%s%s%s", current->title, current->author, current->ISBN);
  //fputs(newline, input_file);    
}
```

That's the relevant part. The commented part I tried, but it put newlines all over, messing with the data that was already nicely formatted.
Here's a little example of how the text file should look (ignore the coloring):

```
Title 1
Last, First
000000 (ISBN)

Title 2
Last, First
111111

etc.
```

When I add a book and the program writes it to the file, it adds it like this (left out ISBN for clarity):

```
...
Title 2
Last, First
First Added Book
Last, First
Second Added Title
Last, First
etc.
```

How can I get an empty line in between each book entry?

Comment: `fgets()` is getting your data with an extra newline (`'\n'`) character added. When you print them to the file, it's getting carried along. A blank line in a file is just the newline character with nothing else.

Comment: Add a `fputs("\n", input_file);` on your `while`.

Comment: I tried adding the \n, but it adds more newlines all over in the text file, not only for the added books.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just insert a newline-character (\n) in this line?

```
fprintf(input_file,"%s%s%s", current->title, current->author, current->ISBN);
```

->

```
fprintf(input_file,"%s%s%s\n", current->title, current->author, current->ISBN);
```

FYI, if you add more \n you get more empty lines.

Comment: Because he hasn't removed the newline from the input so every line will be double-spaced (as commented by @Zak above).

Comment: The way I read this question is, his output format is title, name and ISBN each in one line followed by an empty line to delimit the book. If that's what he wants, then not removing the newline from the input is fine and he has to insert one more after the ISBN.

Comment: I ended up making a function to append a new book to the end of a file, that way it wouldn't mess with the formatting of the books already there. Seems like a dumb solution, but it seems better to break things down into smaller chunks and write functions to handle these chunks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Leaving the `'\n'` in `input`.  (see #4 also)
   This code wants to work with input that has its terminating `'\n'` removed. @Lee Daniel Crocker

   ```
   while(fgets(input, 80, stdin) != NULL) {

     size_t len = strlen(input);
     // Note: under select circumstances, len will be 0.
     if (len > 0 && input[i-1] == '\n') input[--len] = 0;

     // replace `&& input[0] != '\n'` with 
     if (len == 0) break;
   ```
2. Add one or two `'\n'` here.  [@midor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27324282/2410359)

   ```
   fprintf(input_file,"%s%s%s\n", ...
   ```
3. Minor: simplify `malloc()`.

   ```
   // current = (struct book *)malloc(sizeof(struct book));
   current = malloc(sizeof *current);
   ```
4. Check return value on subsequent `fgets()`.  Need to eliminate the trailing `\n'` here too.
5. After `malloc()` consider initializing the entire structure.

   ```
   current = malloc(sizeof *current);
   if (current == NULL) Handle_OOM(); 
   memset(current, 0, sizeof *current);

   // or 

   current = calloc(1, sizeof *current);
   ```